# GKE disk not unmounted on pod crashing. Can't be remounted elsewhere

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Using GKE. I declared a disk I use as persistent volume.

When the pod which uses the volume crashed and was re-started on a different node, the disk was still attached / mounted to the node it was mounted on before.

How comes the volume is not unmounted by the RC?

Then the pod fails and there is no recovery. i didn't find a way to unmount the disk, and the only way I could start the pod again was by restarting until it was started on the node that the disk was mounted on.

That definitely doesn't sound right.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/14642

We're working on a fix: See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15524

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. 
any time frame for a fix? this is a real deal breaker when SLA is to be assured by the RC!

Comment: I can't comment on an ETA, but it will be high pri post v1.1.